# Kotlin null and kotlin.Unit confusion in expression body

Tags: kotlin, generics

Could anyone explain the result of following code snippet? Why the first function call returns kotlin.Unit?

kotlin version 1.5.21, java11

```
fun <T> testMethod(data: String?): T? = data?.let { return null }
println(testMethod<String>(null))  // --> kotlin.Unit

fun <T> testMethod2(data: String?): T? = data?.let { null }
println(testMethod2<String>(null)) // --> null
```

Why the result is different in kotlin 1.4.30 - https://pl.kotl.in/uFZDE3O9e?

Comment: these functions will always return null, even if `data` is not null, is that intended?

Comment: I returned null here for simplicity, in my usecase there was a json deserializer that might return null potentially. That lead to following exception: 

```ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: java.lang.String, and value: kotlin.Unit.```

Comment: you could try adding a cast, e.g.:
`fun <T> testMethod(data: String?): T? = data?.let { return null as T } ?: run {return null}`

Comment: My guess is it has _something_ to do with how, if I'm not mistaken, the `return` in your first version is actually returning out of `testMethod` whereas your second version is equivalent to `return@let null`.

Comment: it's seems it's less the return bit, but the way the `data?.let` construct handles the case when data is null, i.e. default for run?, see here: https://pl.kotl.in/5npN-7Qty

Comment: @Stachu The `return` has to change something, otherwise `data?.let { null }` (and the equivalent `data?.let { return@let null }`) would return `kotlin.Unit` as well. But they don't. Looking at the Kotlin class decompiled to Java, for whatever reason `testMethod` seems to be compiled to `if (data == null) { return Unit.INSTANCE; } else { return null; }`.

Comment: Kotlin 1.5.0 introduced a new JVM backend for the compiler, so it may treat differently non-local returns, as Slaw was saying above. Have you tried adding an issue to the official issue tracker (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) ?

Comment: Looks like some compiler bug. Conversion of `testMethod` function from expression body to block body makes it return `null` https://pl.kotl.in/2Re4WRG7U

Comment: Another way to make it return `null` is the removal of explicit returning type declaration
https://pl.kotl.in/5XW3Rq33I

Comment: @user2340612 thanks for the link - added the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47972

Answer (score 1):

It was a compiler issue and already reported here - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-47527, fixed in 1.6.0-dev-970.

Ref: https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/ae608ea67fc589c4472657dc0317e97cb67dd158